# Counting characters $\bmod q$ under some divisibility conditions

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, characters

Let $N$ be fixed. I would like to estimate the number of primitive characters $\chi_1$ modulo $q_1$ and $\chi_2$ modulo $q_2$ such that
$$q_1q_2 \mid N$$

How can I tackle this?